# Dual booting Window7 and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot

I have window 7 on a 1 TB HDD and I installed ubuntu also. I am not getting dual booting menu, I am not a computer expert, kindly say what I have to do?

Comment: What boots, Windows or Ubuntu. If Ubuntu have you run `sudo update-grub` ? If not add this to Ubuntu live installer in live mode & Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

If you installed ubuntu first then windows second, there could be and issue as the windows boot loader will overwrite changes and doesn't play nicely with ubuntu.

My suggestion is to to install Ubuntu last and grub (Grand Unified Bootloader) will install properly.

If you don't want to go through the hassle then once inside ubuntu

`sudo update-grub2`

Comment: I installed window first and the Ubuntu. But while booting it goes directly to Windows, not showing the menu for choosing the OS

Comment: Hold shift while booting to show the grub menu